# Dart yield stream events from another stream listener

Tags: dart, flutter, stream

I have a function that generates `stream` of specific events. Now I have a stream coming from storage service which has its own events. Looking for a way to yield my events when something changes in the `storage stream`.

This code snippet doesn't do the trick.

```dart
Stream<BlocState> mapEventToState(
    BlocEvent event,
  ) async* {
  if (event is UploadData) {
    yield UploadDataProgress(progress: 0.0);
    final Storage storage = Storage();
    final Stream<StorageEvent> upload = storage.upload(event.data);

    upload.listen((StorageEvent storageEvent) async* {
      print('***** Listener: ${storageEvent.type} - ${storageEvent.progress}');

      if (storageEvent.type == StorageEventType.error) {
        yield UploadDataError(errorMessage: storageEvent.error);
      }

      if (storageEvent.type == StorageEventType.success) {
        yield UploadDataSuccess();
      }

      if (storageEvent.type == StorageEventType.progress) {
        yield UploadDataProgress(progress: storageEvent.progress);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Output:
The debug print works but the events are not sent to listeners.

```
***** Listener: StorageEventType.progress - 0.01924033836457124
***** Listener: StorageEventType.progress - 0.044581091468101464
***** Listener: StorageEventType.progress - 0.6986233206170177
***** Listener: StorageEventType.progress - 1.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dart/Flutter - "yield" inside a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939917/dart-flutter-yield-inside-a-callback-function)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your `yield`s are yielding from the anonymous function `(StorageEvent storageEvent) async* {` rather than from `mapEventToState`.

Simply replacing the `listen()` with an `await for` should work.

```
Stream<BlocState> mapEventToState(
    BlocEvent event,
  ) async* {
  if (event is UploadData) {
    yield UploadDataProgress(progress: 0.0);
    final Storage storage = Storage();
    final Stream<StorageEvent> upload = storage.upload(event.data);

    await for (StorageEvent storageEvent in upload) {
      print('***** Listener: ${storageEvent.type} - ${storageEvent.progress}');

      if (storageEvent.type == StorageEventType.error) {
        yield UploadDataError(errorMessage: storageEvent.error);
      }

      if (storageEvent.type == StorageEventType.success) {
        yield UploadDataSuccess();
      }

      if (storageEvent.type == StorageEventType.progress) {
        yield UploadDataProgress(progress: storageEvent.progress);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if we use Stream<double> instead of a a BlocState(let's say for upload progress), is it possible to catch 'done' with await for? (listen(onDone: (here))

Comment: Yes  https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#receiving-stream-events

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth. I had a similar problem, where I was subscribing to Firebase snapshots and trying to yield events based on the document data.

If I used the await-for paradigm, there was no subscription handle I would get. As a result, it became painful to stop reading the stream when I wanted to close the BLoC.

I found a round-about solution to this.

```dart
Stream<BlocState> mapEventToState(BlocEvent event) async* {
  if (event is FetchEvent) {
    yield LoadingState();
    _subscription = SomeStream(event.someKey).listen((snapshot) {
      add(OnSnapshotEvent(snapshot));
    });
  }

  if (event is OnSnapshotEvent) {
    if (SomeCondition(event.snapshot)) {
      yield SomeResultState();
    } else {
      yield SomeOtherState();
    }
  }
}
```

This way, I have a handle to the subscription, so I can always nicely cleanup.