# Best practice to use mapEventToState with incoming streams?

Tags: flutter, design-patterns, bloc

Is there any elegant way to map incoming streams from a private api directly inside mapEventToState() without having to create redundant private events in the bloc?

I came with this solution. It's ok with one single stream, but with multiple streams it starts to get a mess. Thanks in advance.

```dart
// (don't mind the imports, this is the bloc file)

class ExampleBloc extends Bloc<ExampleEvent, ExampleState> {


  final MyPrivateApi api = MyPrivateApi.instance; // singleton

  ExampleBloc() {
    // api has a stream of booleans
    api.myStream.listen((b) {
    // if it's true fire this event
    if (b) this.add(_MyPrivateEvent());
  }

  @override
  ExampleState get initialState => InitialExampleState();

  @override
  Stream<ExampleState> mapEventToState(
    ExampleEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is _MyPrivateEvent) {
      yield SomeState;
    }
  }



// private Event
class _MyPrivateEvent extends ExampleEvent {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you can subscribe on event updates in your screen, and push event from screen to Bloc if need some calculations. Code will be more clean.

Comment: The problem is that I can't subscribe to a stream inside mapEventToState() , forcing me to have to have private events to then yield the states

Answer (score 0):

Your way seems to be the only way works and seems to be used - see this bloc issue: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/112 and this example project: https://github.com/algirdasmac/streams_and_blocs

Just make sure to `dispose` the subscription that gets returned by `api.myStream.listen`.

**Previous answer**

The following **DOES NOT** work for infinite streams because the generator function will `await` until the stream finishes. This can only be used for stream the complete fast, like maybe an upload/download progress.
See accepted answers here [Dart yield stream events from another stream listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56036503/dart-yield-stream-events-from-another-stream-listener) and here [Dart/Flutter - "yield" inside a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939917/dart-flutter-yield-inside-a-callback-function)

```dart
  ExampleBloc() {
    _MyInitEvent();
  }

  @override
  Stream<ExampleState> mapEventToState(
    ExampleEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is _MyInitEvent) {
      await for (bool b in api.myStream) {
        if (b) yield SomeState;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think it won't work because the streams are not finite and using it on a yield function will stop upcoming events until the await for stream is closed.

Comment: Yes you are right, I guess there is no other way. I am thinking about using bloc in the next project but this is a huge hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

Build another block that encapsulate your stream of bytes.

You can make two events (`ByteRead` and `ByteConsume`) and two states (`ByteWaiting` and `ByteAvailable`).

`Byteread` and `ByteAvailable` should have a `_byte` field for storing data. Your bytebloc has a subscriber listening the stream and every time it reads a byte it fires a `ByteRead` event.

You should also add to the bloc a `consume()` method that gives the last byte readed and fires the `ByteConsume` event.

The two states and events are mutual:

- you start in bytewaiting and every time you have a `ByteRead` you change to `ByteAvailable` and
- every time you have a `ByteConsume` you change back to `ByteWaiting`.